# XBee two-way communication (sender and receiver) at the same time

Tags: java, c, arduino, communication, xbee

Let's say I am trying to make a chat program like in the YouTube video *[XBee Basics - Lesson 2 - Simple Chat Program Between Two XBees in AT Mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPx3TjzvE9U)*.

In this video, he explained that one XBee is a sender which sends "Hello world" to the another XBee using Arduino.

However, is the XBee able to send and receive data at the same time? Are the routers able to communicate to the coordinator and the other way around?

Additionally, I want to write my own software to receive and send data and not using Arduino software. Are there any libraries and APIs?

Articles or videos would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send and receive data at the same time.  When XBee modules are configured in "AT mode" (also referred to as "Transparent Serial"), you configure the DH and DL parameters to identify the destination node that will receive the serial data.

You should definitely spend some time at [examples.digi.com](http://examples.digi.com/) for step-by-step tutorials on setting up various examples like a [two way chat](http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-zb-zigbee-chat/).  The [Quick Reference](http://examples.digi.com/quick-reference/) page includes a long list of libraries in various languages, including the [Digi XBee ANSI C Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) for C and [xbee-api](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/) for Java.

Comment: How do I use 2 series 1 xbee for a 2 way chat

Comment: @timberlake, the examples.digi.com site has just what you're looking for: http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-802-15-4-chat/

Comment: I have a xbee conected to the computer with  a explorer and another xbee the sits on a shield. The xbeesheild has a jumper that switches between xbee/usb. When I have it on the xbee side it can receive msgs and when on usb it can send msgs. I need to do bothat the same ttime. So should I use different pins like rx tx for sending and 3,4 for receiving?

Comment: @timberlake, maybe you should ask that as a separate question here on StackOverflow, instead of having it stuck in these comments.  I don't have direct experience with Arduino and its shields, but someone else who sees your question might.

Comment: ahh thanks.. but i managed to solve the problem. Thanks for your comments